# Drawing on python and pycharm

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am a beginner on Python. I draw a square with this code.

```
import turtle
square=turtle.Turtle()
print(square)
for i in range(4):
    square.fd(100)
    square.lt(90)
turtle.mainloop()
```

However, there is another code for drawing square with this code in the book. Apparently, I tried to copy the exact same thing but it didn't work out. Can someone help me to figure out the problem?

```
def drawSquare(t,sz):
    """Make turtle t draw a square of sz."""

    for i in range(4):
        t.forward(sz)
        t.left(90)
    turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you please state _how_ your code didn't work.

Comment: The program wouldn't run and this appears ============ RESTART: C:/Users/OWM/Documents/Python/new stuff.py ============
>>>

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the function so it will start:

```
import turtle

def drawSquare(t, size):
    for i in range(4):
        t.forward(size)
        t.left(90)
    turtle.mainloop()

drawSquare(turtle.Turtle(), 100)
```